# cursor position in a listview lost when move away from activity

Tags: android, sqlite

I populate ListView with data from a Sqlite database using custom CursorAdapter.

When user moves away from my activity and comes back later I loose the position in my cursor and the ListView is positioned to the first item again.

When skipping startManagingCursor() it works as expected. How do I work around this?

Here is a code snippet called OnCreate():

```
cursor  = db.getAll();      
startManagingCursor(cursor);
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(listview.getContext(), cursor, true);
listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: You may need to store the cursor position in a bundle

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. I couldn't figure out what was causing it, but you are right its the managed cursor and auto-requerying. This seems odd. Why does this convenience conflict with normal ListView behavior, seems like faulty design. Requerying has the potential to bring in completely new data, in which case ListView can't logically restore state. Most of the time though the requery isn't actually changing the dataset so it definitely should restore the position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LatinSuD is correct, you'll want to store the position in the bundle.  The managed cursor is requeried when the activity becomes active again so you'll lose your spot.  You can look at the notepad3 tutorial for an example of saving state information. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html

Comment: I've tried that, but cursorFav.moveToPosition(savedposition); doesn't change a ListView position.

Comment: Try listview.setSelection(savedposition);

Comment: Thanks. Actually I had to remember selected item position in Listview ItemClickListener (listview.getSelectedItemPosition() in touch mode always returns INVALID_POSITION) and then restore it by listview.requestFocusFromTouch(); listview.setSelection(savedposition);